# Error when downloading package (which uses RcppArmadillo) via devtools

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools

I'm trying to download a R package from github using devtools, and I'm running into some problems. From the error message I'm getting, it seems like the problem has something to do with RcppArmadillo, since "dgemv_" seems to be a part of RcppArmadillo. Uninstalling or reinstalling RcppArmadillo doesn't stop the error.

Since I've had this error message, I've uninstalled R, RStudio, and Rtools. I reinstalled R, installed some packages, installed Rtools, and the error is persisting.

---

In R, my session info is:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppArmadillo_0.9.100.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19      magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.4.0     devtools_2.0.0    pkgload_1.0.1     R6_2.3.0          rlang_0.3.0       tools_3.5.1      
 [9] pkgbuild_1.0.2    sessioninfo_1.1.0 cli_1.0.1         withr_2.1.2       remotes_2.0.1     assertthat_0.2.0  digest_0.6.18     rprojroot_1.3-2  
[17] crayon_1.3.4      processx_3.2.0    callr_3.0.0       base64enc_0.1-3   fs_1.2.6          ps_1.2.0          curl_3.2          memoise_1.1.0    
[25] glue_1.3.0        compiler_3.5.1    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.2   prettyunits_1.0.2
```

When I run:

```
devtools::install_github("irinagain/mixedCCA")
```

I get the error message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo irinagain/mixedCCA@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSQ7zwU\remotes2a5c2e561667\irinagain-mixedCCA-af59bb9/DESCRIPTION' (406ms)
-  preparing 'mixedCCA':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'mixedCCA_0.1.0.tar.gz'

* installing *source* package 'mixedCCA' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c find_w12.cpp -o find_w12.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mixedCCA.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o find_w12.o -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/i386 -lR
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[__ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE]+0x361): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[__ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE]+0x622): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE[__ZN4arma27glue_times_redirect2_helperILb0EE5applyINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEEEEvRNS3_INT_9elem_typeEEERKNS_4GlueIS7_T0_NS_10glue_timesEEE]+0xa6b): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_[__ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_]+0x18c): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_[__ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_]+0x43a): undefined reference to `dgemv_'
find_w12.o:find_w12.cpp:(.text$_ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_[__ZN4arma5ProxyINS_4GlueINS_3MatIdEENS_3ColIdEENS_10glue_timesEEEEC1ERKS7_]+0x987): more undefined references to `dgemv_' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mixedCCA'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.1/library/mixedCCA'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/ben/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSQ7zwU/file2a5c4fb94283/mixedCCA_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the BLAS and LAPACK libraries are not mentioned during linking. For this to happen, the package author should use something like

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

in `src/Makevars(.win)`. This happens automatically when one uses `RcppArmadillo::RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` to set-up the package. However, `mixedCCA` does not have a `Makevars` file at all: https://github.com/irinagain/mixedCCA/tree/master/src. You should open an issue on GH to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Not an Rcpp issue, or RcppArmadillo issue because it shows

```
other attached packages:
[1] RcppArmadillo_0.9.100.5.0
```

that RcppArmadillo is loaded just fone.

I suggest you open a ticket at the `mixedCCA` repo.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I get the error even when RcppArmadillo isn't loaded. Are you thinking that despite the error message being about (what I believe to be) an Armadillo object (`dgemv_'), the package would likely only fail to download if there was a problem with the package?

Comment: You are mistaken. That is a *LAPACK* routine.  You are barking at the wrong tree.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I perhaps should have said "an object only involved since Rcpp is being used" rather than "an Armadillo object". For what it's worth, the text "dgemv" never appears in any file in the package.

Comment: True dat.  Someone may be calling a high-level function that dispatches to code ultimately calling this.  But the facts remain that a) R provides that for us b) it generally works c) RcppArmadillo has 500+ packages using it d) they work on Windows too.  So while I remain ignorant of the details here I'd still start with that package _especially_ if it is off CRAN and hence less inspected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following :

- clone the repo locally
- create a file src/Makevars.win containing the line : PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
- install.packages('path/to/the/repo', repos=NULL, type='source')